# SetExpressCheckout VAT not properly calculated by Paypal

Tags: paypal

I need to setup a payment using the paypal API and display the VAT calculation on the Paypal page, I am using the [SetExpressCheckout](https://cms.paypal.com/uk/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_SetExpressCheckout) method.

My problem is : Paypal include the 20% VAT in the NET price, then set taxes as 0% in the payment details. It should display the full detail of the transaction (net + 20% in 2 rows as it is for most of the Paypal payments I experienced)

Here are the parameters I am using :

```
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=120
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=100
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=20
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&RETURNURL=http://xxxxx.com/paypalCheckout/orderconfirm.php
&CANCELURL=http://xxxxx.com/paypalCheckout/ordercancel.php
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=GBP
&REQCONFIRMSHIPPING=0
&NOSHIPPING=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=100
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT0=20
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=My+ItemXXX
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0=Digital
```

The documentation & a web search didn't gave me much information about it.
Thanks for your help.